# Unpermitted parameters despite whitelisting attribute rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, devise

I have an attribute :completed, that is a boolean value (true/false). On the index page, I have a check box that I would like to, when checked, update that value for the object. Here is what I have for the check box:

```
<div class="task_area">
      <%= link_to task.title, task_path(task), class: 'wrapper_task_name'%>
      <%= form_for task do |f| %>
        <%= f.check_box :completed %>
        <%= f.submit 'update' %>
      <% end %>
</div>
```

I whitelisted the attribute :completed in my tasks_controller.rb:

```
def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :text, :boolean, :current_user, :email, )
end
```

But in the log I get:

```
Started PATCH "/tasks/45" for ::1 at 2016-10-16 17:35:43 -0400
Processing by TasksController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"���", "authenticity_token"=>"ogAki1fvq6Eq+ONwjxeYwf+ZOrmkv+EAuDmZRTEEJ05xB3cf/XyHEavNDZyBWUOL0gUuEOglyM2uDNoJHcDcJg==", "task"=>{"completed"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"update", "id"=>"45"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Task Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."user_id" = $1 AND "tasks"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", "1"], ["id", 45]]
Unpermitted parameter: completed
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
```

I'm wondering if having devise require user authentication is causing this problem. Does anyone have any idea as to what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I do not see that you have whitelisted the attribute :completed  in the tasks_controller.rb

Answer (score 4):

The name of the field is `:completed` not `:boolean` - this is what you need to put in your permit line. eg:

```
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:title, :text, :completed, :current_user, :email)
end
```

Also can I *strongly* recommend against having `:current_user` a a permitted field? This will allow a malicious user to create a task for another user. I'd leave it off the permitted list and add it manually in the create method eg with `current_user.tasks.create(task_params)`

Comment: +1 about current_user. The current user should be obtained from the session. The same applies to field email if you are using it to identify the user who sends the request

Answer (score 0):

```
def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :text, :current_user, :email, :completed)
end
```

With the code above completed is whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the type(`boolean`) of `completed_at` in your white-listed params of `tasks_controller`. It should be like this

```
def task_params
 params.require(:task).permit(:title, :text, :completed, :current_user, :email)
end
```